# Setting the line length for caption

Tags: spacing, graphics

I am trying to use subfigure to put two figures beside each other and unfortunately LaTeX puts them to the right. I used `hspace` to reduce the space between them and that results in messing up the captions. So I thought the solution might be to change the length of line that makes the caption line break automatically.

```
\begin{figure}[~hbt]
\subfigure[Nonuniform distribution of points on sphere when the $n$-spherical coordinates are uniformly chosen from related intervals]
{
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{sphere}
}
\hspace{-3em}
\subfigure[Nonuniform distribution of points on cube when the points on left figure has been transformed using the mentioned diffeomorphism]
{
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{cube}
}

\end{figure}
```

Any other solution is welcomed as well.

Comment: The problem is the width of them. Replace `scale=0.4` by `width=.45\linewidth` and use `\hfill` between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `subcaption` package (the `subfigure` package is deprecated).

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{sphere}
        \caption{Nonuniform distribution of points on sphere when the $n$-spherical coordinates are uniformly chosen from related intervals}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{.06\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{cube}
        \caption{Nonuniform distribution of points on cube when the points on left figure has been transformed using the mentioned diffeomorphism}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption for the overall figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Nice. IMHO it would be better to use `.45` instead of `.5`. So we get a space.

Comment: @Sigur You won't get space in between the two subfigures, because they are centered automatically and the caption stretches over the whole width. You need to manually `\hspace{...}`.

Comment: @Sigur See my updated answer.